# Is there a way to normalize the scales of axes in subplots in cufflinks library python?

Tags: python, plotly, subplot, axes, cufflinks

I have used cufflinks to plot a few subplots, their scale ranges are different. I want same scales so I can compare the subplots. Is there a way to customize the axes of each subplot in cufflinks?

[image: screenshot]

This link shows the picture of the subplots, the subplots of row 1, column1 and column2 have different ranges on the y axes. Is there a way to change the range of graph DRV.FV to -5 to 10?

**MCVE:**

df=cf.datagen.lines(4)

df.iplot(subplots=True, subplot_titles=True, legend=False)

I have taken this from [the official plotly website.](https://plot.ly/python/v3/ipython-notebooks/cufflinks/#subplots)

Don't be alarmed if you run this and get a different sub plot because every time the data generated is random. So the plot will be different. The question here is just how to obtain same scale ranges on the sub plots.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](/hepl/mcve) and not just a plot. Read about [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) too.

Comment: @rpanai Is it alright now?

Comment: Hi @A.Ametov the other post got closed, you may assess the question over here, thanks!

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same problem...

Comment: @Alex Poca Hi, no I wasn't able to do it, i just let my axes be as they are, all different. Were you able to discover how?

Comment: @ka1357, Alas not yet. I am working on it. I will let you know if I succeed.